# Multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker error get when try to insert data into database in c#

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker error get when

try to insert data into database in c#.

I try to search solution to debuge 
this code but i can't get anythink from it.now help me to resolve this.

```
    public void insertdatarootmasterDetails(TblRootMasterDetail objstud1)
    {
         DBLaxmiTatkalEntities2 objentity1 = new DBLaxmiTatkalEntities2();         
         objentity1.TblRootMasterDetails.AddObject(objstud1);
         objentity1.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AddObject function for adding newly created items. It seems like objstud1 is previously selected from the EF context. In this case you should use the Attach function instead.

```
objentity1.TblRootMasterDetails.Attach(objstud1);
objentity1.Entry(objstud1).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
objentity1.SaveChanges();
```